# How to find all nodes with the same value of a tree

Tags: c++, tree, set, c++17, red-black-tree

I need to find all nodes with the same value in a pom tree to find out all id of overlap intervals.

I created two unordered_set and a key_set() function which traversal all nodes in the tree and add id to the unordered_set recursively.

```
template <class T, class K>
class Node
{
public:
    Color color = BLACK; //color
    T id; //key
    K value = NULL; //value
    K pom;
    int p;
    int max;
    int sum;
    Node* parent; //parent
    Node* left; //left child
    Node* right; //right child
}

template <class T, class K>
void RBTree<T, K>::key_set(unordered_set<T> lower_set, unordered_set<T> higher_set, Node<T, K>* node, K value)
{
    if ((node->value != NULL))
    {
        if (node->value <= value && node->p == 1)
            lower_set.insert(node->id);
        else if (node->value >= value && node->p == -1)
            higher_set.insert(node->id);
        key_set(lower_set, higher_set, node->left, value);
        key_set(lower_set, higher_set, node->right, value);
    }
}
```

I think it because of scope or other reasons, the sets will always have a size of zero at last, which should have the same size as the max of the root node.

Comment: How to find all nodes with the same value of a tree? @bloody

Comment: Do you know dfs, bfs, etc.?

Comment: You pass your `unordered_set`s by value. This makes a copy of the set and passes that copy to the callee - any changes made to that copy by the callee are **not** visible to the caller. Consider: `void f(x) { x = 42; } int y = 0; f(y);  // y is still 0, not 42`

Comment: Ahhhh, I totally forgot it is value passing in C++ instead of reference passing. I created a global variable to store those value, maybe I'd better change it to pass a pointer. Thank you so much @IgorTandetnik